# $\forall v\in V(v\neq 0 \implies \exists \lambda\in \mathbf{F}(Tv = \lambda v))\implies \exists k\in\mathbf{F}\forall v\in V(Tv = kv)$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Is my attempt at the following Proof Correct?

We also have the following result.

**$(25)$** Given that $T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$ and $u$ and $v$ are eigenvectors of $T$ such that $u+v$ is also an eigenvector then $u$ and $v$ correspond to the the same eigenvalue.

**Theorem.** Given that $T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$ such that every non-zero vector in $V$ is an eigenvector of $T$ show that $T$ is a scalar multiple of the linear opearator.

**Proof.** Let $u$ be any non-zero vector in $V$, consequently $Tu = ku$ for some $k\in\mathbf{F}$. Now let $v$ be an arbitrary non-zero vector in $V$ and consider the following Cases.

*Case-1($v\neq -u$):* Since $v$ is not the additive inverse of $u$ it follows that $u+v$ is non-zero and consequently $T(u+v) = \lambda(u+v)$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbf{F}$ and thus by appealing to result **$(25)$** we may deduce  that $k = \lambda$.

*Case-2($v = -u$):* We know that $Tu = ku$ thus by appealing to the homogenity of $T$, we have $T(v) = T(-u) = T((-1)\cdot u) = (-1)\cdot Tu = (-1)\cdot ku = k\cdot(-1)\cdot u = k(-u) = kv$.

Consequently $\forall u\in V\backslash\{0\}(Tu = ku)$.

$\blacksquare$

Comment: The title to your post is extremely confusing. It makes it sound like you're trying to prove every nonzero vector is an eigenvector which is clearly false in general. You should change the title to reflect what you're actually asking. Don't make the reader struggle to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems correct, but it's easier. Given $u,v\in V$, you know that
$$
T(u)=\alpha u,\qquad
T(v)=\beta v\qquad
T(u+v)=\gamma(u+v)
$$
If $u$ and $v$ are linearly independent, we have therefore
$$
\alpha u+\beta v=\gamma u+\gamma v
$$
which yields $\alpha=\gamma$ and $\beta=\gamma$.

If $u$ and $v$ are linearly dependent there is nothing to prove, because they surely belong to the same eigenspace.